# How do I capture a protected page's url in query string?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Beware with me for a second as I try to lay the background to my issue.

So I having using the python web framework [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) close to a year now and it has a wonderful extension called [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that helps provide user session management kind of like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication) in laravel.

Having said all that, there is a certain feature in Flask-Login that provides the functionality that when a user is not logged or signed in and tries to access that a page that requires one to be authenticated for example `/create_post`, they will be redirected back to the login page with that page encoded in the query string like `/login?next=%2Fcreate_post`.

Am trying to implement the same feature in a laravel project that am working on so I can redirect the user to the page they probably wanted to go to in the first place or to a different route in case that query string doesn't exist and I cannot seem to find where to put my code to do just that and I don't want to mess with anything in the `vendor` directory(because of the obvious issues that come with that), and I have tried manipulating the file `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` by doing what is below but with no success.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    $previous_url = url()->previous(); // how do I insert this in query string

    return $next($request);
}
```

Will I have to create my own middleware or is there another way of implementing this kind of feature in laravel?

**NOTE:** I am not using the default laravel authentication system. I have created my own controller `SessionsController` to handle logins which contains the below code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class SessionsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['create', 'login']);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Login',
            'body_class' => 'hold-transition login-page',
        ];

        return view('auth.login', $data);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = User::checkCredentials($request->username, $request->password);
        if (!$user) {
            return back()->with([
                'class' => 'alert-danger',
                'message' => 'Please check your credentials',
            ]);
        }

        // set session active flag to true
        $user->session_active = true;
        $user->save();

        auth()->login($user);
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $user->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $user->session_active = false;
        $user->save();

        auth()->logout();

        return redirect()->route('login')->with([
            'class' => 'alert-success',
            'message' => 'You logged out successfully',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes you will have to create your own middleware ad the built in redirect is using Laravels authentication system. However I would recommend you to switch to Laravels own auth system as that is tied into the system and a lot of third party packages.

Comment: @misorude I have added the code, hope that helps.

Comment: @OliverNybroe thank you for the tip but I tried something else. You check it out in my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to somewhat solve my issue even though I didn't use query strings as I had wanted.

I create a helper function `get_previous_url` as shown below

```
/**
 * Gets the previous url
 * 
 * @return null|string
 */
function get_previous_url()
{
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $previous_url = url()->previous();

    // check if previous url is from the same host
    if (!str_contains($previous_url, $host)) {
        return null;
    }

    // get the previous url route
    list(, $route) = explode($host, $previous_url);

    // make sure the route is not the index, login or logout route
    if (in_array(substr($route, 1), ['', 'login', 'logout'])) {
        $route = '';
    }

    return $route;
}
```

And then I called the same function in my `SessionsController` class in the **create method** by doing this

```
public function create()
{
    $previous_url =  get_previous_url();
    if ($previous_url) {
        session(['previous_url' => $previous_url]);
    }

    ... 
}
```

And then I changed my **login method** to

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    ...

    $redirect = redirect()->route('dashboard'); // '/'
    if (session()->has('previous_url')) {
        $redirect = redirect(session()->pull('previous_url'));
    }

    return $redirect;
}
```

Comment: Btw there is also a redirect()->back() method

Comment: @OliverNybroe I wanted a way to store it and use it later, not immediately,